# Magento API - proper home URL

Tags: magento2

I got my Magento2 installed. Admin site is easy accessed on:
http://devstore.panstore.eu/magento2/web/adminedit/admin

If I try:
http://devstore.panstore.eu/magento2/web/rest/products

I get: 
**Specified request cannot be processed.**

If I try:

```
http://devstore.panstore.eu/magento2/web/rest/oauth_authorize?auth_consumer_key=consumer_key&oauth_consumer_secret=consumer_secret
```

I get same response: specified request cannot be processed.

I think my base URL is wrong.

What is base URL in my example? 
How to authorize to be able to call list of products service.

Unfortunately, Magento documentation is totally useless for quick startup.
There are no any functional postman collection, no easy step by step guides to jump in. I didn't find the solution on NET.

Answer (score 0):

After very long studying, result is here and is real time saver.

In my particular case, base url is: http://devstore.panstore.eu/magento2/web

Token for authentication you simply get with this URL:

your_token = http://base_url/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=your_user&password=your_pass

your_user and your_pass are defined in Magento admin users, add also appropriate roles.

After you receive token, add this header to GET request:

Authorization: Bearer **your_token**

and simply call Magento 2 services by REST path (this one gets one product with SKU = 24-MB01):

http://base_url/rest/default/V1/products/24-MB01